# Using present instead Future

Tags: meaning

**"He wins the league" vs "He will win the League"**

Do both sentences express same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. The simple present can carry the meaning of historical action that is likely to continue. (This is sometimes called the *enduring present*.) So we can imagine the following conversation:

> **A**: Who do you think **will win** the club's golf tournament?
>   **B**: Bob, of course. He ***wins*** every year.

Person B expects that Bob will win this year (and years into the future).

But we can also imagine the following:

> **Announcer**: Bob hits a magnificent shot off the tee on the last hole. And, it's a hole in one. Bob **wins** the tournament!

This is just a declaration what's happened just now. There's no implication for next year or any time in the future.